# End Conversation in Seam when the user leaves the page

Tags: javascript, seam, seam-conversation

Is there some way to end a conversation in Seam 2 when the user leaves the page? I know, that I can of course end a conversation in the navigation rules( see [this post](http://community.jboss.org/message/478346#478346)), but I want to end a conversation when the user enters an url in the address bar of the browser.

Could this be achieved via Javascript (for example with onbeforeunload)? But how to stop a conversation via javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to end a conversation when the user enters an url in the
>   address bar of the browser.
>
> Could this be achieved via Javascript (for example with
>   onbeforeunload)? But how to stop a conversation via javascript?

You could use JavaScript to implement an `onbeforeunload` event and use AJAX to communicate the user leaving to the site and end all your conversations. However, I don't recommend you this solution because you cannot rely on a event happening on the browser, Javascript is not a good option, since you can disable it client-side (Not only that, but the browser may crash, the network connection may drop, etc..)

I think an alternative aproach to do this is by setting a seam `conversation timeout` on the server. You can try and reduce the timeout in order to close inactive conversation faster, when the user leave your page.

Configuring the conversation-timeout period can be accomplished through the following in your `components.xml`:

```
<core:manager conversation-timeout="700000" />
```

Notice that conversation-timeout only affects `background` conversations, `foreground` conversation will only timeout when the session times out which is relevant for your requirements.

More information about conversation time out can be found in this [article](http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2007/12/13/explaining-the-conversation-timeout-setting-through-example/).

Comment: Very interesting thoughts on my issue, it really does not seem, that Javascript is the right solution here. Thanks for the link, I did not know that there are foreground and background conversations.